# On an html page, is javascript the only way to programatically manipulate the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, scripting

Is JavaScript the only language that can be run on the client side in a browser for client side scripting like DOM manipulation? I think VBS used to be available in older versions of internet explorer, but is no longer available?

With about a zillion server side languages, I have only really seen JavaScript on the client side. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is it possible to use any other scripting language for client code? Do any browsers natively (or at least reasonably) allow for scripting in another language, or accessing the DOM directly in some other way? I am aware of using clever CSS3 for things like nested menu items, so not that.

Comment: Yes, server side can only change the document if there is a postback/refresh.

Comment: "You only need JavaScript". Someone's going to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than JS or no JS, it's the HTML(5) and ECMAScript spec that matters. It really depends on browser to implement the specs. For example Google uses V8 for JS processing. For local storage Google and MS uses IndexedDB (for html5) while others uses different client db (like FF and Safari-SQL Lite - I think).

Not sure about VBS in IE anymore but it's not supported in any other browser anyway. And IE is sort of very much behind the curve.
JS is now de-facto standard in browser world and gaining popularity even in Server side with the help of node.js ...

To be more specific - there are other languages available for browsers and multiple efforts took place (and going on) to present a logical substitute for JS. Example - VBS, PERL, TCL, Python plugin in FF etc - but none became a viable option against JS (especially with multiple JS frameworks showing up almost everyday).

Other approach was Flex / Silverlight type environment which essentially provide a viewport on top of browser to overcome limitations of HTML. But with present HTML5 specification, the trend is reverse now - all are flocking around HTML5 and JS.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript is supported by Internet Explorer. You can use ActionScript and Java Applet at the client side too.